# Error installing pure-ftpd

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ftp

I'm getting a very weird error when installing pure-ftpd on my Ubuntu 12.04.04 LTS server.

I'm running this command, with a sudo user.

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
```

and I get this error

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up pure-ftpd (1.0.35-1) ...
Starting ftp server: File/Basename.pm did not return a true value at /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper line 23.
invoke-rc.d: initscript pure-ftpd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing pure-ftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pure-ftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and then it just aborts the installation. I've installed pure-ftpd on my other machine just fine this way.

Comment: Lucky I have a 12.04 LTS server running right now, I'll test this.

Comment: Thank you Vasili! I installed it on my other 12.04 LTS machine just fine, but it doesn't work on this machine for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preliminary Steps

Clean up your packages and update the cache:

```
sudo apt-get purge pure-ftpd
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
```

---

## If reinstalling PureFtpd  doesn't work

This is **line 23** of `/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper`:

```
use File::Basename;
```

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) is a Perl module.
I tried installing it using:

```
$ cpan
cpan[1]> install File::Basename
```

But the install failed with the error:

> Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

**However**, it did mention that `File::Basename` is part of the `perl-5.18.2` distribution.
So I upgraded Perl:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade perl --no-install-recommends
```

After that I could verify that it was installed using:

```
$ cpan
cpan[1]> i File::Basename
```

---

## If you cannot install the Perl module

**Question:** When you use `cpan` and type `i File::Basename`, what comes up?

**Response:**

> autouse.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 182. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 182. Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 8. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.

**Next Step:**

Reinstall perl with

```
sudo apt-get install Perl --reinstall
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get purge Perl
sudo apt-get install Perl
```

**(WARNING: Purging Perl can affect a LOT of dependencies and other applications)**

Comment: I'm quite new to Linux, I tried running the same upgrade on perl but it seems as it didn't upgrade it, or I'm running the latest version of it.

Comment: when you use `cpan` and type `i File::Basename`, what comes up?

Comment: This comes up after I type cpan: `autouse.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 182.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.14/App/Cpan.pm line 182.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.`

Comment: That suggests there is an issue with Perl itself............ Completely reinstall Perl and see how that goes. `apt-get purge perl`

Comment: That removed my MySQL server, well I got a fresh backup of it so it's fine. Although when removing perl, the system went into read-only mode, so couldn't do anything. I will have to reboot the machine.

Comment: When it came back up, did reinstalling Perl work? I realised shortly after my last comment that `sudo apt-get install Perl --reinstall` would have been a better command. Next time.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine now. Thanks alot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome, good to hear :)